# How to set global proxy in ubuntu from configuration URL?

Tags: networking, proxy

I am on a network which uses Automatic Proxy with authentication. I have been provided a configuration URL, configuring that in web browser I am able to surf web.

**How do I configure this type of proxy system wide?**

What I am trying is adding configuration URL in All settings->network->Network Proxy in the format

method :: Automatic

Configuration URL :: username:password@http://www.something.com/someting/someting

But it doesn't seem to working.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

You can set your proxy via the terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

You should, for that, edit the following files:

```
    /etc/bash.bashrc
    /etc/environment
    /etc/apt/apt.conf
    /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

These files must have the following contents:

```
    sudo nano  /etc/bash.bashrc


    export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
    sudo nano  /etc/environment


    http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf


   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
   Acquire::https::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
   Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
    sudo nano  /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf 


    HTTPProxyServer proxyserver.net
    HTTPProxyPort port
    HTTPProxyUsername username
    HTTPProxyPassword password
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

And:

```
Configuration URL = http://username:password@www.something.com/someting/someting:port
```

Comment: I do not have the address of the proxy server. I think they are using multiple proxy servers and it is being assigned when request arrives.

Comment: Most companies that run a proxy server will offer an autoconfiguration URL.  This URL usually leads to a "proxy.pac" or "wpad.dat" on a web server.  This is the preferred way of offering a proxy configuration since it allows flexibility to the system administrator to dynamically change your settings. If you have been provided an autoconfiguration URL you can enter it in "Automatic proxy configuration"

Comment: I am doing the same.. But this step is followed by an authentication. I am not able to figure out how I should provide username and password to access the internet system wide.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the write up. The only "problem" is that multiple applications invent multiple ways of defining proxy settings. In order to address that, I've created a shell script which defines proxy settings in multiple ways. See it here: https://github.com/frgomes/debian-bin/blob/master/bash_80proxy.sh